# Remove the lowercase vowels [C]

Tags: c, error-handling, computer-science

I'm learning C and I got a task to to remove the lowercase vowels  (a, e, i, o, u) in a given string.
so I wrote this code and I'm getting Segmentation fault error in line 15, can someone explain me why I'm getting this error, how to avoid getting this error, and how to solve this error?

Thx, appreciated!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *shortcut(char *str_out, const char *str_in);

int main()
{
    shortcut("", "how are you today?");
    return 0;
}

char *shortcut (char *str_out, const char *str_in)
{
    for (int i = 0; str_in[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (str_in[i] != 'a' && str_in[i] != 'e' && str_in[i] != 'i' && str_in[i] != 'o' && str_in[i] != 'u')
            *str_out++ = str_in[i];
    }

    *str_out = '\0'; // write to str_out
    return str_out; // return it
}
```

Comment: Modifying string literals is undefined behavior.  Look at your first parameters.

Comment: Use a modifiable array of characters, i.e. `char something[100]; shortcut(something, "abc123");`

Comment: why are comparing against 0 in your for loop?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is the task "Create a function called shortcut to remove the lowercase vowels (a, e, i, o, u ) in a given string." this is the given code to start ```char *shortcut (char *str_out, const char *str_in)
{
  *str_out = '\0'; // write to str_out
  return str_out; // return it
}```

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil instead of calculating the elements in the array I just used it...

Comment: @Patton13 So what's wrong with using the array I mentioned already?  Have you tried it yet?  Bottom line is that you cannot modify string literals, no matter what "task" was given you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yea I tried it, I don't get the error now but it fails on the task...

Comment: Even if you *could* modify the string literal, `""` doesn't have room to be written to.

Comment: The program doesn't output anything...

Comment: Not just because you don't print anything, but because `return str_out` points to "the empty string". Presumably you are using, following @PaulMcKenzie, `printf("%s\n", shortcut(something, "how are you today?"));` You need to return the *original value* of the pointer.

Comment: Understood thanks you all!